How do I export a pdf document from a shiny app?
I'm trying to generate a pdf with stored data in a shiny app. But the data don't appear in the document.
It looks like the data are not transferred from the app to the pdf, or that maybe the storage doesn't work. I don't know which one is it. Could you help me please ?
Here's the global :
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinymeta)
library(rmarkdown)
library(npreg)


##### Générer rapport #####
create_pdf_content <- function(user_data, file_path) {
  # rmd_file <- "report.Rmd"
  # pdf_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
  
  # Rendre le document R Markdown en PDF
  rmarkdown::render(
       "rapport.Rmd", 
        output_file = file_path, 
        params = list(user_data = user_data),
        output_format = "pdf_document"
  )
}

###### Etape 1 #######
# Stockage des informations personnelles
save_user_data <- function(age, sexe, taille, sport, niveau, haute_intensite, intensite_moderee, assis, commentaires) {
  data_from_step1 <- list(
    Age = age,
    Sexe = sexe,
    Taille = taille,
    #Poids = poids,
    Sport = sport,
    Niveau = niveau,
    Haute_intensite = haute_intensite,
    Intensite_moderee = intensite_moderee,
    Assis = assis,
    Commentaires = commentaires,
  )
  
  return(data_from_step1)
}

Here's the server :
function(input, output, session) {
# copie  
  reactive_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  #data_from_step1 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  complete_exercice <- NULL # Initialisation de complete_exercice
  seuil <- 1
  
  ####### Etape 1
  
  observeEvent(input$go1to2,{
    updateNavbarPage(session, "navbar", selected = "étape 2")
    
    # Appel de la fonction de stockage des données
    data_from_step1 <- save_user_data(
      input$age,
      input$sexe,
      input$taille,
      input$sport,
      input$niveau,
      input$haute_intensite,
      input$intensite_moderee,
      input$assis,
      input$commentaires
    )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
######## ETAPE 4
  
  output$downloadButton <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("rapport_utilisateur_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      
      # Récupérer les données stockées à l'étape 1
      user_data <- data_from_step1
      
      
      # Vérification pour s'assurer que user_data est un data frame
     # if (!is.data.frame(user_data)) {
       # user_data <- as.data.frame(t(user_data))
     # }
      # Chemin du fichier temporaire pour le PDF
      temp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
      
      # Générer le PDF
      create_pdf_content(user_data, temp_file)
      
      # Copier le fichier PDF généré dans le répertoire de téléchargement
      # Copier le fichier temporaire du PDF dans le fichier de sortie
      file.copy(
        from = temp_file,
        to = file)
    }
  )
}

Here's the markdown :
---
title: "Rapport"
output: pdf_document
params: 
  user_data: ""
  Age: NA
  Sexe: NA
  Taille: NA
  Sport: NA
  Niveau: NA
  Haute_intensite: NA
  Intensite_moderee: NA
  Assis: NA
  Commentaires: ""
  plot1: NA
  plot2: NA
  plot3: NA
  plot4: NA
  content: ""
  title: ""
  header: ""
  results: ""
  footer: ""
---

# Informations de l'utilisateur

- **Sexe** : `r user_data$Sexe`
- **Taille** : `r user_data$Taille` cm
- **Sport** : `r user_data$Sport`
- **Niveau de pratique** : `r user_data$Pratique`
- **Nombre d'heures à haute intensité dans la semaine** : `r user_data$Haute_intensite`
- **Nombre d'heures à intensité modérée dans la semaine** : `r user_data$Intensite_moderee`
- **Nombre d'heures assis dans la semaine** : `r user_data$Assis`
- **Commentaires** : `r user_data$Commentaires`

